# How to use MongoDB connection globally

Tags: c#, mongodb, connection, singleton, mongodb-.net-driver

My API is on .net mvc c# platform. I am using mongo DB to drop and store data the following way. It is not working properly when I try to drop and insert data concurrently. The connections are multiplying and the requests are not executed in the same order. How can I use the MongoDB in a global class with only one connection open? do give some reference to look into.

```
public static string DB= DBConnection.MongoDB;

    public bool Insert(Data data)
    {
        try
        {
            var con = new MongoClient(DBConnection.ConnectionString);
            var db = con.GetDatabase(DB);
            db.InsertOne(data);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            
        }
    }

using System.Configuration;

namespace DataAccess.Implementations
{
    internal class DBConnection
    {
        #region ConnectionString
        public static string ConnectionString { get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; } }
        #endregion
        #region Database
        public static string MongoDB{ get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDB"].ToString(); } }
        
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Singleton pattern:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e152212-2109-4d07-adbf-4ff0326c077b/how-to-establish-db-connection-using-singleton-pattern?forum=csharpgeneral

[Singleton design pattern is preferred to get a DB Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866194/singleton-design-pattern-is-preferred-to-get-a-db-connection)